# Trouble understanding this assembly code

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I have an exam comming up, and I'm strugling with assembly. I have written some simple C code, gotten its assembly code, and then trying to comment on the assembly code as practice. The C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
   int x = 10;
   char const* y = argv[1];

   printf("%s\n",y );

   return 0;
}
```

Its assembly code:

```asm-x86
   0x00000000000006a0 <+0>: push   %rbp                   # Creating stack
   0x00000000000006a1 <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp              # Saving base of stack into base pointer register
   0x00000000000006a4 <+4>: sub    $0x20,%rsp             # Allocate 32 bytes of space on the stack
   0x00000000000006a8 <+8>: mov    %edi,-0x14(%rbp)       # First argument stored in stackframe
   0x00000000000006ab <+11>:    mov    %rsi,-0x20(%rbp)   # Second argument stored in stackframe
   0x00000000000006af <+15>:    movl   $0xa,-0xc(%rbp)    # Value 10 stored in x's address in the stackframe
   0x00000000000006b6 <+22>:    mov    -0x20(%rbp),%rax   # Second argument stored in return value register
   0x00000000000006ba <+26>:    mov    0x8(%rax),%rax     # ??
   0x00000000000006be <+30>:    mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)    # ??
   0x00000000000006c2 <+34>:    mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax    # ??
   0x00000000000006c6 <+38>:    mov    %rax,%rdi          # Return value copied to 1st argument register - why??
   0x00000000000006c9 <+41>:    callq  0x560              # printf??
   0x00000000000006ce <+46>:    mov    $0x0,%eax          # Value 0 is copied to return register
   0x00000000000006d3 <+51>:    leaveq                    # Destroying stackframe
   0x00000000000006d4 <+52>:    retq                      # Popping return address, and setting instruction pointer equal to it
```

Can a friendly soul help me out wherever I have "??" (meaning I don't understand what is happening or I'm unsure)?

Comment: If your class is in Assembly programming, reading compiler generated code is not going to be of help. It's likely to be detriment in this stage of your education.

Comment: you can try using `gcc -c -S -fverbose-asm file.c` - that should generate `file.s` with commented ASM

Comment: It helps to single-step thropugh the assembler with your debugger, taking note of the actions on registers, memory etc.

Comment: @StoryTeller My upcoming exam will have questions like "Rewrite the above X86-assembler program in C", so I thought by practicing the other way around I could benifit.

Comment: @Hako - Is this a course in reverse engineering? If not, I doubt you'll need to understand the C to machine code transform :) Either way, assembly programming, like all programming, is about writing code that other people will understand. That's why compiler generated code can be a problem. Though it's not bad if you need help understanding a specific ABI

Comment: @StoryTeller The course is "Computer Systems", and the question is under the category "Machine architecture" :) I see your point.

Comment: @MortenJensen thanks for the tip!

Comment: @MartinJames thanks for the advice :)

Comment: You should also check optimized output of compiler, your current assembly is unoptimized -O0 updating stack frame and local variables after each line of source to make debugging in C source "per line" possible, the machine code generated without that feature will be considerably different (also much shorter, and probably easier to understand from the point of pure assembly ... and a bit harder to rewrite back into C source, at that point you must basically do asm -> algorithm -> write C from scratch, while the unoptimized code can be reconstructed almost literally by asm->C back-translation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to make a guess:

```
mov    -0x20(%rbp),%rax   # retrieve argv[0]
mov    0x8(%rax),%rax     # store argv[1] into rax
mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)    # store argv[1] (which now is in rax) into y
mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax    # put y back into rax (which might look dumb, but possibly it has its reasons)
mov    %rax,%rdi          # copy y to rdi, possibly to prepare the context for the printf
```

When you deal with assembler, please specify which architecture you are using. An Intel processor might use a different set of instructions from an ARM one, the same instructions might be different or they might rely on different assumptions. As you might know, optimisations change the sequence of assembler instructions generated by the compiler, you might want to specify whether you are using that as well (looks like not?) and which compiler you are using as everyone has its own policy for generating assembler.

Maybe we will never know why the compiler must prepare the context for printf by copying from rax, it could be a compiler's choice or an obligation imposed by the specific architecture. For all those annoying reasons, most of people prefer to use a "high level language" such as C, so that the set of instructions is always right although it might look very dumb for a human (as we know computers are dumb by design) and not always the most choice, that's why there are still many compilers around.

I can give you two more tips:

1. you IDE must have a way to interleave assembler instructions with C code, and to single step within the assembler. Try to find it out and explore it yourself
2. the IDE should also have a function to explore the memory of your program. If you find that try to enter the 0x560 address and look were it will lead you. It is very likely that that will be the entry point of your printf

I hope that my answer will help you work it out, good luck

Comment: It was unclear to me why  the `mov %rax,%rdi` was there, thank you :)

Comment: OP compiled without optimizations.  It's fairly normal to see really weird stuff when disabling optimizations. I recommend to compile with at least `-O1` to get the most basic optimizations in.

Answer (score 5):

```
   0x00000000000006ba <+26>:    mov    0x8(%rax),%rax     # get argv[1] to rax
   0x00000000000006be <+30>:    mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)    # move argv[1] to local variable
   0x00000000000006c2 <+34>:    mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax    # move local variable to rax (for move to rdi)
   0x00000000000006c6 <+38>:    mov    %rax,%rdi          # now rdi has argv[1]
   0x00000000000006c9 <+41>:    callq  0x560              # it is puts (optimized)
```

Comment: Thank you! So the first line is because arg[1] is not in the stackframe, so we have to move it into another register fist, before we can move it into an address in the stackframe?

Comment: yes, because x86 and x64 don't have general memory to memory instruction (some exists but not for general use)

Comment: You don't have to copy it, it's just unoptimized code. Notice it's writing `rax` into memory, then reloading it and then transferring to `rdi`. Those 3 instructions can be replaced by a single `mov 0x8(%rax), %rdi`